# problem after i found sql injection when using sqlmap tool

Tags: mysql, sql

I found SQL injection vulnerability with sqlmap tool and it looks like this

```
sqlmap resumed the following injection point(s) from stored session:
---
Parameter: xxxxx (GET)
    Type: boolean-based blind
    Title: OR boolean-based blind - WHERE or HAVING clause
    Payload: xxxxx=-1102 OR 2628=2628
---
[19:41:37] [INFO] the back-end DBMS is MySQL
```

---

but when i try to find the --dbs , --tables,  i get this

[image]

I don't know what this is and how i can solve this problem. I also tried it on linux and found the same issue

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried to find the '--dbs, --tables'?

Comment: sorry, i have modified and uploaded an image . i don't know why it looks like this to me.  [INFO] retrieved: \xfe  t \xfd\xc2   \xc0/ \x9e\xa9\xe4h`\xc1  \xff\xf9\xff\xff\xe8u \xfe   \xe4k